# Overlapping buttons in job search and job listing

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, design, browser-support

I noticed that the button layout is a bit kooky on the job search and job listings pages:

- Job search: overlapping button and boxed prompt (also the unicorn email prompt appears to be... breathing?).

[image: job search]

- Job listing full width layout, none of the buttons are aligned correctly

[image: full width layout]

- Job listing compact layout, same story

[image: compact layout]

**I'm assuming there should be no overlaps, and on the listing pages the white buttons should be aligned.**

The only browser available to me at work is IE11, not sure if it's a conscious decision for it to not be fully supported/tested... believe me I'd be using another browser if I could.

Comment: I'm in Safari 12.0 on macOS 10.14 Beta, and there's no layout problem for me. Isn't IE on its way out? I doubt they'll spend more resources at testing in that browser. It could simply be an error in one of IE's engines. You should see if the problem persists in for instance ME, on another computer.

Comment: @Andreas hence my comment about not knowing which browsers they are trying to support

Comment: According to [this FAQ post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/) IE 11 should be supported...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We do indeed support IE11. Thank you for bringing this to our attention. The `flex` property implies `display: flex` everywhere except IE. I added a `display:flex` property to the container- the buttons are now properly aligned.